# How to hide h:selectManyListbox default scroll

Tags: jsf, jsf-2

i hava **h:selectManyListbox** with **size=3** and there's a default disabled scroll appears, i want to hide it, and show it when necessary (if size >3 ).

please advise how to do that, thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

something like this

```
<h:selectManyListbox styleClass="#{(myBean.hideScroll gt 3)?'':'myHideScrollClass'}"...
```

where in your css

```
.myHideScrollClass {

 }
```

Or a bit simplified

```
 <h:selectManyListbox style="#{(myBean.hideScroll gt 3)?'':'overflow-y:hidden;'}"...
```

---

Also , instead of `myBean.hideScroll gt 3` you can use `myBean.myList.size() gt 3` but make sure `myList` is not a `null`

Answer (score 0):

`<h:selectManyListbox />` render 'select' and 'option' html tag. You can't control the look of a select box in such detail, it is displayed depends on the system.
You can use some trick(condition **size=3**: you can use @Daniel approach):

```
<style type="text/css">
 .test { 
    display:inline-block; 
    vertical-align:top; 
    overflow:hidden; 
    border:solid grey 1px; 
 }
 .test select { 
    padding:10px; 
    margin:-5px -20px -5px -5px; 
 }
</style>
<div class="test">
<h:selectManyListbox />
</div>
```